# Take picture with Camera and use as "profile Picture" within app

Tags: ios, swift, image, camera, crop

I have a UIImageView that I want to open the camera so that the user can take a picture, crop it (the hard part), and then have the app store it in a class I've already written.  I've never worked with the camera before, so I'm not too sure how to go about doing this.

Comment: Look into `UIImagePickerController`

Comment: I'll post an answer that will show you how to do it, but you should still read the docs about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement the `UIImagePickerController` - that also means that you need your `ViewController` to conform the to the `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` and the `UINavigationControllerDelegate`.  First make sure your ViewController does this:

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
```

Then you can create a method that will show the camera:

```
func showCamera() {
    // Check if the device has a camera
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera) {

        // Device has a camera, now create the image picker controller
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false

        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
    else {
        NSLog("No Camera")
    }
}
```

Then you must have this method as part of the `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` which will handle the image taken by the user with their camera:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    // To dismiss the image picker
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    let chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage

    // Do whatever you wish with the image
}
```

You should also note that Apple has now instituted new privacy protocols. If you want access to the user's camera or photo library, you need to go to your `Info.plist` and add an `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription` - otherwise your app will crash when trying to access the camera. Go to your plist and insert a new row, then just paste `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription` and they'll automatically convert it to say something like "Privacy - Camera access". You then have to enter a description in the value column as to why you need to access the camera. This description will be shown to the user when they initially are asked to allow your app access to the camera.

Also if you want your user to crop the image after they take the picture, change that `allowsEditing` value when you instantiate the `UIImagePickerController` to `true`

Comment: So I don't have to build my own cropping method? it's built in?

Comment: I believe so - you'll have to try it out for yourself, but I think it's possible to just use the one Apple already created. Why re-invent the wheel?

Comment: good point.  Thank you for the in depth response.

Comment: @GabeSpound - Sure thing, good luck!

Comment: Got it all added and functioning properly.  Thank you!